# Add a shopping cart in guest mode, and then register a new account, the additional_options of the shopping cart will be deleted,？

Tags: magento

**Preconditions and environment**
Magento version：2.3.7

**Steps to reproduce：**
Add to cart as a visitor
Register a new account
Some specifications of the shopping cart: info_buyRequest, additional_options are missing

**Expected result：**
Create a new account, the specifications of the shopping cart added as a guest should exist instead of being changed

**Actual result：**
Some specifications of the shopping cart: info_buyRequest, additional_options are missing

GitHub link：[enter link description here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35591)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get，最新版magento2.4：vendor\module-checkout\Model\Session.php 有了修复，同步最新版即可

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Magento not deleting additional_options, Options are merge with customer cart.

Thanks,